# Setting up PWM on PA.3 of the STM32F091RC Nucleo board

Tags: pwm, stm32, stm32f0, stm32cubemx, hal-library

I am using STM32Cube and the HAL libraries to set up the PWM.

For initializing Timer 2, I have:

```
void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /**TIM2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA3     ------> TIM2_CH4 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF2_TIM2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspInit 1 */
  }

}
```

and:

```
void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 800;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2);

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig);

  HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim2);

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig);

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 400;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_LOW;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_4);

}
```

Both of the above were generated by STM32CubeMX.  In main, I added two lines to start the timer and the PWM channel:

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_4);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}
```

The code compiles and downloads, but I do not see a PWM output at PA3 (I'm measuring with a logic analyzer).  PWM output also doesn't work at PA4. I've tried switching from TIM2 to TIM15 to check if that works, but there is also no PWM output.

To verify my code, I tested a few other PWM pins (PA10, PB3, PB5, PB4, PA8, PA9, PA6, PA5) and they all work.  Are there unique settings for pins PA3 and PA4 to get PWM output working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often on dev boards, some pins may be used by other functions on the board, such as a display, buttons, LEDs, etc. There are probably a bunch of solder bridges on the back of the board that serve to disconnect a pin on the microcontroller from the GPIO headers because when they are being used by something else on the board.

Take a look at the user manual and see if PA3 and PA4 are being used for some other function on the board. ST often includes the schematics for the dev board, and it should show the solder bridges on it as well.

Comment: Thanks!  From the manual, it looks like the solder bridge is the problem.